# Swift map array unexpected argument type

Tags: arrays, swift, cloudkit

I have the following code with a map, why is the `log` also an array instead of just a `CKRecord` object?

```
sharedDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
  if let error = error {
    reject("there is error", "no logs", error)
  }else{
    NSLog("found results")
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let resultLogs = records.map { log in
      // Log is also an array: [CKRecorder] so I'll get error:
      // Value of type '[CKRecord]' has no member 'object'
      return [
        "log": log.object(forKey: "log") ?? "N/A" as __CKRecordObjCValue,
        "createdAt": formatter.string(from: log.creationDate ?? Date.init())
      ]
    }
    resolve(resultLogs)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with completion handlers that return an Optional value and an Optional error, you should always optional bind the value while checking if the error is `nil` or not. This will solve your issue caused by the fact that the you're trying to call `Optional`'s `map` instead of that of `Array`.

```
sharedDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
    guard let records = records, error == nil else {
        return reject("there is error", "no logs", error!)
    }
    NSLog("found results")
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let resultLogs = records.map { log in
      return [
        "log": log.object(forKey: "log") ?? "N/A" as __CKRecordObjCValue,
        "createdAt": formatter.string(from: log.creationDate ?? Date())
      ]
    }
    resolve(resultLogs)
}
```

Comment: You can safely force unwrap `records` if error is `nil`.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. Just started using Swift for the first time. One syntax problem with your example, it says: `'guard' body must not fall through, consider using a 'return' or 'throw' to exit the scope` so I had to return the `reject`

Comment: @vadian I prefer force unwrapping `error`, since if `records` is used in several places, it's easier to optional bind it than force unwrapping every time it's accessed

Answer (score 1):

[Because the `map` function also exists on `Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map). Note the lack of a `?` after `records`. You probably want to unwrap it in a `guard` first, or add the `?` to use optional chaining on the entire expression.